# Add class to table in div containing <a> with specified href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation where I need to add a class to a table, but only if the table is inside a **div** with id 'mydiv' AND there is a row in table containing an <a href=...> element where the **href** contains the term 'myref', including the quotes. Is this easy in jQuery and if so, how do I do this? I just can't work out how to change an element while referring forward and backwards to others.

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work (I am relatively new to jQuery, as you can probably see from the below):

```
$('.mydiv').find('td').find('a[href]').contains('myref').parent.parent.addClass('myclass')
```

The following html snippet simulates my situation (I cannot change the html, just add some javascript and css):

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    <a href='blahblah'>Some text</a>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="some href">Some text</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:some javascript containing 'myref' in quotes">Some text</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="some href">Some text</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:some javascript without match">Some text</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id='otherdiv'>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="some href">Some text</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:some javascript containing 'myref' in quotes">Some text</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The first table needs to get the new class, the second and third don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `has()` method to find the `table` elements which contain the `a` required along with the 'attribute contains' selector to get the `href` with `myref`. Try this:

```
$('#mydiv table').has('a[href*="myref"]').addClass('myclass');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/w5e0g3jt/)

Comment: That is a very easy way to do something seemingly quite complicated. Definitely have to go and learn more jQuery. Thank you for this.

Comment: @Kees This is the best answer, Very optimized one. No problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your searching for a class with the name `mydiv - $(".mydiv")` instead of searching for an ID

Change your code like this :)

```js
$("#mydiv").find("td").find("a[href*='myref']").parents("table").addClass("myClass");
```

```css
.myClass {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mydiv'>
    <a href='blahblah'>Some text</a>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="some href">Some text</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:some javascript containing 'myref' in quotes">Some text</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="some href">Some text</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:some javascript without match">Some text</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id='otherdiv'>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="some href">Some text</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:some javascript containing 'myref' in quotes">Some text</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` on the target `td` to find it's parent (`table`). And then `$.each()` for checking every `td` in the `first` table and `indexOf()` to find the specific text of `href`.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phtLowzx/2/)

Code snippets:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mydiv table:first td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('a').attr('href').indexOf('myref') != -1)
      $(this).closest("table").addClass('myclass');
  });
})
```

```css
.myclass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mydiv'>
  <a href='blahblah'>Some text</a>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="some href">Some text</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:some javascript containing 'myref' in quotes">Some text</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="some href">Some text</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:some javascript without match">Some text</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id='otherdiv'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="some href">Some text</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:some javascript containing 'myref' in quotes">Some text</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That almost worked. Unfortunately it is not always the first table (and there could be more than one) so I changed `$('#mydiv table:first td').` to `$('#mydiv td').` and then it seems to work (the class gets aplied). However I have just noticed that I get the following error in this code, which stops other javascript further down from working: 'TypeError: $(...).find(...).attr(...) is undefined', any idea what could cause that?

Comment: Never mind, just found the problem, had to change the if statement to: `if ($(this).find('a').attr('href') && $(this).find('a').attr('href').indexOf('myref') != -1)`